# Swift 3 looping JSON data

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, struct, swifty-json

I'm attempting to loop through a JSON array sending data to a struct.

Here's my code that uses SwiftyJSON to return a `JSON` object:

```
performAPICall() {
    json in
    if(json != nil){
    print("Here is the JSON:")
    print(json["content"]["clients"])

        let clients = json["content"]["clients"]
        for client in clients {
            var thisClient = Client()
            thisClient.id = client["id"].string
            thisClient.desc = client["desc"].string
            thisClient.name = client["name"].string
            self.clientArray.append(thisClient)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
        print("Something went very wrong..,")
    }
}
```

I'm not quite sure why I'm getting "has no subscript" errors on the three strings.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

**EDIT:** Here's a sample of the JSON

```
{
    "content": {
        "clients": [{
            "group": "client",
            "id": "group_8oefXvIRV4",
            "name": "John Doe",
            "desc": "John's group."
        }, {
            "group": "client",
            "id": "group_hVqIc1eEsZ",
            "name": "Demo Client One",
            "desc": "Demo Client One's description! "
        }, {
            "group": "client",
            "id": "group_Yb0vvlscci",
            "name": "Demo Client Two",
            "desc": "This is Demo Client Two's group"
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON object?

Comment: I've added it to the question.

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that, I forgot to include the top "top" level, but it's defiantly there if I just print(json).

Comment: Using SwiftyJSON to download it, it's the JSON that comes out of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `array` method. Thus, your line

```
let clients = json["content"]["clients"]
```

should use `array` (and unwrap it safely):

```
guard let clients = json["content"]["clients"].array else {
    print("didn't find content/clients")
    return
}

// proceed with `for` loop here
```